# GraphQL query to access first item in an array?

Tags: graphql

Had a good search, but can't seem to find anything for this. Is there a way in GraphQL to only access the first item in an array?

Something like:

```
query {
  allDBItems {
    edges {
      node {
        exampleArray([0])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, GraphQL does not provide any syntax for manipulating the request, outside of conditionally including/excluding fields using the `@skip` and `@include` directives.

The GraphQL service you are querying *may* support a way to limit the result set for a field to a specific length by providing an argument on the field like `limit`, `first` or `last`. However, it's up to the server to include these fields as part of the service's schema and to provide the logic to implement them. Check your API's documentation to see if these fields are supported.

Any manipulations of the response have to be done client-side. There is an experimental [`graphql-lodash`](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash) library that lets you do this right inside your queries -- but at the end of the day, the data is still being transformed client-side.

Comment: I think this approach will undermine the GraphQL ability to statically verify upfront if an operation is valid before deployment.

Answer (score -1):

NOT this way - there is no such 'client only' syntax.

General rule **'ask for what you need'** requires an explicit expression when passing [named] parameters (variables).

**Just tell your API what you need** - pass a `limit` (and `index`?) parameter - sth recognizable for your API [resolvers].

Without that you can just use only the first of all returned array elements - suitable only for small datasets.

Read graphql docs about pagination.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. So you can't put a limit on the size of the returned arrays? As in, you can only retrieve the full arrays? I have some very large arrays and need only the first item in each. I'm guessing you can't use ```(first:x)``` on an individual array.

Comment: You can pass variables to tell API how many records you need - resolver should use this parameter for SQL LIMIT (f.e.).