# GraphQL filtering an array

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I am using GatsBy GraphiQL to write a query to return a single element, but the query returns all of the elements.
Here is my testing data:

```json
    {
      "data": {
        "mKT": {
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "Apple",
              "description": "apple's desc"
            },
            {
              "name": "Orange",
              "description": "orange's desc"
            },
            {
              "name": "Banana",
              "description": "banana's desc"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "extensions": {}
    }
```

And, here is the GraphQL query:

```json
    query MyQuery {
      mKT(data: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: "Apple"}}}) {
        data {
          name
          description
        }
      }
    }
```

I expect to get:

```json
    {
     "name": "Apple",
     "description": "apple's desc"
    }
```

However, running the query returns all of the data.
Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
query MyQuery {
  mKT(data: {filter: {name: {eq: "Apple"}}}) {
    data {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

The `filter` keyword should do the trick.

Check the [GraphQL Reference (in Gatsby docs)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/) for further details.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the filter keyword in this data structure. Getting this error:
 "Cannot query field \"mKT\" on type \"Query\"."

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your `localhost:8000/___graphql`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same case as:

[GraphQL query to access first item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55827337/graphql-query-to-access-first-item-in-an-array)

You cannot use filters, limits, etc to an structure if it have not been defined on the source.

If you have access to the source, add something like `limit` to the field data.

If not, you will get the full array, and you have to process it on your side.